# Error when publishing from VS 2015 - The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update 1. I have a single solution, with a single ASP.NET web application project. I publish it by right-clicking on the project node, and clicking "Publish".  I've setup a publish profile for FTP. Credentials work/tested/etc.  Server connectivity is good.

However, when publish from Visual Studio 2015, it says "The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed."

Things I've tried:
- Validating FTP server name and credentials.
- Clean/Rebuild
- Restarting Visual Studio.
- Kicking it (hard).

Things I did not try:
- Restarting PC. 
- Repairing Visual Studio.
- Sacrificing a goat.

I do NOT have Xamarin installed, but I do have Tools for Apache Cordova.
I do NOT have VS 2013 (or any prior version) of VS installed.

[image]

Comment: I tried the Goat...  Still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well with VS2015 Update 1, no Xamarin, no VS2013.

I installed the [RC2 for Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/update2-prereleases) and the issue went away.  I looked at the bugs fixed and didn't see this issue mentioned explicitly, but I am publishing now so...

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by doing a repair on VS 2015. I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer, because whatever "Repair" did for me, must've been part of the Update 2.  My guess is that somehow the FTP components are removed by some extension or update, but put back on during a repair or install of VS (or VS update).